# Creating default object from empty value - after php upgrade

Tags: php

I have upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4 now are my class broken and I do not understand it why.

I have build this class:

```
class _g
{
    public static $init;

    public static function init()
    {
        if ( self::$init == null ) 
        {
            self::$init->sysLang = ( isset( $_SESSION['SYSTEM_LANG'] ) ? $_SESSION['SYSTEM_LANG'] : 'dk' );
            self::$init->apiPath = CSS_API_PATH .'theme/'. API_THEME_PATH_GFX .'/gfx/';
        }

        return self::$init;
    }
}
```

And I get this error message:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/html/.....

And I really do not understand how I can fix this problem?

Comment: what kind of type is `_g::$init`, can you provide full error?

Comment: the provide error its what i type, i don't get eny orther error. and type? its a static var / object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should read article about [how to migrate to PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.php).

You don't have any object instantiated in the `init` viariable.
In PHP 5.3 it generates `Strict Standards` but in PHP 5.4 this is a `Warning`.

`E_STRICT` is not a part of `E_ALL` in PHP 5.3, but since PHP 5.4 it is.

You should follow those standards so you should change your code to have the following line in the `if` statement:

```
self::$init = new stdClass();
```

Comment: somthing are worng, need to search more on it when i came home, will it help if i reinstall the server to Debian 5.6? i think maby the PHP version and the newer MySQL make trobules.. :S

Comment: Its working now! :) thanks a lot and i have a small mysql errors to ;) but its working now and thanks! :)